# How do i create new database in Tryton

Tags: python, python-2.7, tryton

I have downloaded and installed Tryton 4.0(client 4.0.exe,windows). I have been playing around with the demo database that comes with it.My question is how do i create my own database and user profile. I went to manage profiles,Added new profile,input port number for postgres databse(5432) and input username.But it says "failed to connect to server".What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to install your custom server, you can not created databases on the demo server. Once you have [installed](http://doc.tryton.org/4.0/trytond/doc/topics/install.html#topics-install) and [configured](http://doc.tryton.org/4.0/trytond/doc/topics/configuration.html#topics-configuration) the server you have to create the database in your database backend. If you are using the postgresql backend you can follow the procedure explained in [their docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

Once you have created this database you must [initialize your database](http://doc.tryton.org/4.0/trytond/doc/topics/setup_database.html#initialize-a-database).

Once the database is created, [start the server](http://doc.tryton.org/4.0/trytond/doc/topics/start_server.html#topics-start-serverhttp://) and the database should be available to select on the profiles page of the tryton client.

Comment: i installed the trytond server,but whats the name of the configuration file ?

Comment: You can use what ever name you want. You just need to create a new file with the configs that you need to modify and then specify it when running trytond.